# What potential drawbacks are there to the following query creation method?

Tags: java

Below is a version of a method used to create a query for a database running PSQL.

```
protected Query createQuery(String hql, Object... queryArgs) {
    final Query query = createQuery(hql);
    for (int i = 0; i < queryArgs.length; i++) {
        Object arg = queryArgs[i];
        query.setParameter(i, arg);
    }
    return query;
}
```

This method does not allow for handling of the character ' in any of the varargs, assuming of course that it is not handled in a different method elsewhere in the program.

Below is a potential modification to this method to allow for handling of this character.

```
protected Query createQuery(String hql, Object... queryArgs) {
    final Query query = createQuery(hql);
    for (int i = 0; i < queryArgs.length; i++) {
        Object arg = queryArgs[i];
        if(String.valueOf(arg).contains("'")){
            query.setParameter(i, String.valueOf(arg).replace("'", "''"));
        }else{
            query.setParameter(i, arg);
        }

    }
    return query;
}
```

Are there any cases under which this modification would fail, and would this modification be likely to cause a notable increase in the time the method would take to complete?

Alternatively, is there a more elegant solution to escaping the ' character for insertion in to a database?

Comment: maybe I dont understand You, but WHY do You such thing? Goal seems ... starnge

Comment: Because at present, in the rare event that the server processes a ' , it does not handle it properly and causes an exception. Aside from telling the client not to send data containing ',  unsure of what can be done.

Comment: `commons-lang` library has class `StringEscapeUtils` which has method `escapeSql()`. So if you already has that dependency in your project you could use that class

Comment: @Ivan we do indeed, will raise that as a possible solution.

Comment: NEVER correct one error with symmetric errro in different place. Correct the first.

Comment: parameters are free on apostrophe problem. WHAT library / framework do U use?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't fix clients that do not understand what is and isn't practical. Framework used is Hibernate.

Comment: Can I tell You once more? Escaping parameters is not required. In reality this is change in data

Comment: Escaping the ' is necessary. otherwise it leads to statements such as: |... where name ilike '%O'Connel%' | and that does not work, that is bad SQL.

Comment: No! No! No! Bad SQL is when glued (naive string concatenated). NOT with hibernate parameters. BTW my first choice test data is O'Hara :) Btw show query example (`hql` string)